# WCAG guidance regarding secured/hosted fields for PCI (Payment Card Industry) Compliance

Tags: accessibility, pci-compliance, wcag, wcag2.0

I'm looking for some additional WCAG guidance regarding secure fields needed for PCI (Payment Card Industry) compliance for ecommerce.  Payment providers now offer a solution for a higher level of conformance where each payment field (credit card number, CVV, and expiration date) is a DOM-injected iframe, comprising of a `label`, `input`, error validation, styling, and focus management.  These iframed fields are referred as "secure fields".
We are working with our payment provider to improve their markup, however, if they followed all form and iframe related guidelines, would there be any other concerns regarding accessibility?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should be good if you're trying to conform to WCAG (either 2.0 or 2.1), but it might depend on your country too.  Different countries have different laws regarding accessibility.  Some laws are stricter or have variations from WCAG.

For example, in the US, if you're working on an airline website, specifically booking and paying for travel (as it relates to your PCI question), it would fall under the [Air Carrier Access Act](https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer/passengers-disabilities).

However, there is nothing specific in WCAG that pertains to PCI.  Just follow the general guidelines of WCAG as you mentioned (labelled fields, error handling, etc).

One item that might pertain to your situation is that <iframe> elements often need a `title` attribute so that screen readers know the purpose of the iframe.  But in your case, if each iframe is an input field, and the fields are labelled properly, then the iframe shouldn't need a title.  The user doesn't care that you used iframes.  They just want to book and pay for their flight.  An iframe title comes more into play when the iframe contains a map or some other "big" user interface component.